# Positive Operator: Norm Estimate

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory, hilbert-spaces, banach-spaces, spectral-theory

In class we encountered the statement:
$$H\geq C1\quad(C>0)\implies\|\mathrm{e}^{-\beta H}\|<1\quad(\beta>0)$$
How does one prove this?

Moreover, what about the weakened version:
$$H\geq C1\quad(C\geq0)\implies\|\mathrm{e}^{-\beta H}\|<1\quad(\beta\geq0)$$

Comment: Are you missing another condition on $C$? Because what if $T = 2I$?

Comment: Hmm, the situation is even worse since in class we're dealing with unbounded operators. The actual statement was: $$H\geq C\mathrm{Id},C>0\Rightarrow\|\mathrm{e}^{-\beta H}\|<1,\beta\in\mathbb{R}$$

Comment: Must be $\beta > 0$. For $\beta = 0$, you have $e^{-0H} = I$ with norm $1$, and for $\beta < 0$, the norm is $> 1$.

Comment: Yes right I corrected it

Comment: Since $H$ is unbounded, how do you define $e^{-\beta H}$? If it's using the spectral theorem, then the observation that $|e^{-\beta t}|\le 1$ on the spectrum of $H$ should be enough.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get the result you want using only $C_{0}$-semigroup theory. Because $H \ge C > 0$, then $K=-H+CI \le 0$ is the generator of a contractive $C_{0}$-semigroup $e^{tK}=e^{tC}e^{-tH}$. So $\|e^{tC}e^{-tH}\|\le 1$, which implies $\|e^{-tH}\| \le e^{-tC}$ for all $t \ge 0$.

Comment: By the semigroup did you mean the holomorphic functional calculus for selfadjoint operators $\Phi_K(e^{t\,\cdot}),t\geq 0$ and what is meant by $\mathcal{C}_0$ and why is it contractive?

Comment: You don't need anything as strong as holomorphic. It is enough to show that $\|\lambda(\lambda I-K)^{-1}\| \le 1$ for all real $\lambda > 0$. Such an estimate is straightforward for $K^{\star}=K \le 0$. Then the $C_{0}$ semigroup $S(t)$ is guaranteed to satisfy $\|S(t)\|\le 1$ for all $t$. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hille-Yosida_theorem#Hille-Yosida_theorem_for_contraction_semigroups

Comment: Now I understand your answer. ^^